# Building an array of numbers no repeating order doesn't matter (Gaming stats)

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, numbers, permutation, game-development

So I play heroes of newerth. I have the desire to make a statistical program that shows which team of 5 heroes vs another 5 heroes wins the most. Given there are 85 heroes and games are 85 choose 5 vs 80 choose 5, that's a lot of combinations.

Essentially I'm going to take the stats data the game servers allow me to get and just put a 1 in an array which has heroes when they get a win [1,2,3,4,5][6,7,8,9,10][W:1][L:0]
So after I parse and build the array from the historical game data, I can put in what 5 heroes I want to see, and I can get back all the relevant game data telling me which 5 hero lineup has won/lost the most.

What I need help starting is a simple algorithm to write out my array. Here's similar output I need: (I have simplified this to 1-10, where the code I get I can just change 10 to x for how many heroes there are).

[1,2,3,4,5][6,7,8,9,10]

[1,2,3,4,6][5,7,8,9,10]

[1,2,3,4,7][5,6,8,9,10]

[1,2,3,4,8][5,6,7,9,10]

[1,2,3,4,9][5,6,7,8,10]

[1,2,3,4,10][5,6,7,8,9]

---

[1,2,3,5,6][4,7,8,9,10]

[1,2,3,5,7][4,6,8,9,10]

[1,2,3,5,8][4,6,7,9,10]

[1,2,3,5,9][4,6,7,8,10]

[1,2,3,5,10][4,6,7,8,9]

---

[1,2,3,6,7][4,5,8,9,10]

[1,2,3,6,8][4,5,7,9,10]

[1,2,3,6,9][4,5,7,8,10]

[1,2,3,6,10][4,5,7,8,9]

---

[1,2,3,7,8][4,5,6,9,10]

[1,2,3,7,9][4,5,6,8,10]

[1,2,3,7,10][4,5,6,8,9]

---

[1,2,3,8,9][4,5,6,7,10]

[1,2,3,8,10][4,5,6,7,9]

---

[1,2,3,9,10][4,5,6,7,8]

---

[1,2,4,5,6][3,7,8,9,10]

[1,2,4,5,7][3,6,8,9,10]

[1,2,4,5,8][3,6,7,9,10]

[1,2,4,5,9][3,6,7,8,10]

[1,2,4,5,10][3,6,7,8,9]

[1,2,4,6,7][3,5,8,9,10]

[1,2,4,6,8]...

[1,2,4,6,9]

[1,2,4,6,10]

[1,2,4,7,8]

[1,2,4,7,9]

[1,2,4,7,10]

[1,2,4,8,9]

[1,2,4,8,10]

[1,2,4,9,10]

...

You get the Idea. No repeating and order doesn't matter. Its essentially cut in half doesn't matter the order of the arrays either. Just need a list of all the combinations of teams that can be played against each other.

EDIT: additional thinking...

After quite a bit of thinking. I have come up with some ideas. Instead of writting out the entire array of [85*84*83*82*81][80*79*78*77*76*75] possible combinations of characters, which would have to be made larger for the introduction of of new heroes as to keep the array relevant and constantly updating.

To instead when reading from the server parse the information and build the array from there. It would be much simpler to just make an element in the array when one is not found, ei the combinations have never been played before. Then parsing the data would be 1 pass, and build your array as it complies along. Yes it might take a while, but the values that are created will be worth the wait. It can be done over time too. Starting with a small test case say 1000 games and working up the the number of matches that have been played. Another Idea would be to start from our current spot in time and build the data base from there. There is no need to go back to the first games ever played based off the amount of changes that have occurred to heroes over that time frame, but say go back 2-3 months to give it some foundation and reliability of data, and with each passing day only getting more accurate.

Example parse and build of the array:

```
get match(x)
if length < 15/25, x++; //determine what length matches we want and discredit shorter than 15 for sure.
if players != 10, x++; //skip the match because it didn't finish with 10 players.
if map != normal_mm_map // rule out non mm games, and mid wars
if != mm, rule out custom games
//and so forth

match_psr = match(x).get(average_psr);
match_winner = match(x).get(winner);

//Hero ids of winners
Wh1 = match.(x).get(winner.player1(hero_id)))
Wh2 = match.(x).get(winner.player2(hero_id)))
Wh3 = match.(x).get(winner.player3(hero_id)))
Wh4 = match.(x).get(winner.player4(hero_id)))
Wh5 = match.(x).get(winner.player5(hero_id)))

//hero ids of losers
Lh1 = match.(x).get(loser.player1(hero_id)))
Lh2 = match.(x).get(loser.player2(hero_id)))
Lh3 = match.(x).get(loser.player3(hero_id)))
Lh4 = match.(x).get(loser.player4(hero_id)))
Lh5 = match.(x).get(loser.player5(hero_id)))

//some sort of sorting algorithim to put the Wh1-5 in order of hero id from smallest to largest

//some sort of sorting algorithim to put the Lh1-5 in order of hero id from smallest to largest


if(array([Wh1, Wh2, Wh3, Wh4, Wh5],[Lh1,Lh2,Lh3,Lh4,Lh5],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]) != null)
array([Wh1, Wh2, Wh3, Wh4, Wh5],[Lh1,Lh2,Lh3,Lh4,Lh5],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]) +=     array([],[],[1],[][][][](something with psr)[][][[])

else(array.add_element([Wh1, Wh2, Wh3, Wh4, Wh5],[Lh1,Lh2,Lh3,Lh4,Lh5],[1],[][][][](something with psr)[][][[])
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Is it necessary that the answer of your program requires (H1,H2,H3,H4,H5) vs (L1,L2,L3,L4,L5) where H[1-5] must have defeated the same team L[1-5] ?? Or can it be that H[1-3] defeated L[3,4] and H[4,5] defeated L[1,2,5] ??

Comment: It could be broken down that way? I'm guessing the point was to was to be able to pick one enemy hero and using a search you can see what 5 person team has the greatest winning percentage va that one hero. Then you can pick two enemy Heroes and it shows similar. To include you can pick your teams Heroes so say I pick 2 of my teams heroes and 2 of the enemies. It will show was 3 heros I should pick on my tream that have the best winning percentage va those two enemy heroes picked and also fill in their best team vs what I have picked. 

Hope that helps clear up any confusion.

Comment: Each number is associated with a hero id and heros are non repeating. But I don't think was necessarily the question.

Comment: Tree idea - at top of tree add hero 1 then add 4 branches 1 of each teammate then add oops team string to each leaf. (personal note to attack this problem from different angle)

Answer (score 1):

Encode each actor in the game using a simple scheme 0 ... 84 
You can maintain a 2D matrix of 85*85 actors in the game. 
Initialize each entry in this array to zero.

Now use just the upper triangular portion of your matrix. 
So, for any two players P1,P2 you have a unique entry in the array, say array[small(p1,p2)][big(p1,p2)].

array(p1,p2) signifies how much p1 won against p2.

You event loop can be like this :

```
For each stat like H=(H1,H2,H3,H4,H5) won against L=(L1,L2,L3,L4,L5) do
    For each tuple in H*L (h,l)  do
         if h<l
           increment array[h][l] by one
         else
           decrement array[l][h] by one
```

Now, at the end of this loop, you have an aggregate information about players information against each other. Next step is an interesting optimization problem.  
wrong approach : select 5 fields in this matrix such that no two field's row and column are same and the summation of their absolute values is maximum. I think you can get good optimization algorithms for this problem. Here, we will calculate five tuples (h1,l1), (h2,l2), (h3,l3) ... where h1 wins against l1 is maximized but you still did not see it l1 is good against h2. 
The easier and correct options is to use brute force on the set of (85*84)C5 tuples.

Comment: by calculating five tuples (h1,l1),.. it shows the win of hero 1 vs hero 2, based off just the comparative of what the 2 lowest hero id number is?

Comment: I am confused how you analyze across different hero selections beyond the first tuple.

Comment: Example: Team 1: hero 1(ID:55)... Team 2: hero 6(56)... When hero 1 is changed to say for example (3) how does it know its a different team because you incremented (3) + 1 and (55) + 1 both vs (56) and not the rest of team 2

Comment: you use P1, and P2. In a given match there are 5 people playing on 1 team, so its a 5v5 or 10 players (human)

Comment: for comment 1 and 3 : see I am having one integer for any set of player (p1,p2). This integer indicates how much p1 won against p2. If it is negative then it indicates that p2 has won more games against p1. I am not considering individual games here. For any stat in your game like H=(h1,h2,h3,h4,h5) won against L=(l1,l2,l3,l4,l5), just use a cross product of H and L to generate 5*5=25 tutples. Its like h1 won against l[1-5].

Comment: for comment 2: I did not understand your question